# Verb meaning 'turn & close'

Tags: word-request

My dad's really strong; when he closes something like a jar or a tap you can't get it open easy. My friend was trying to get a jar open but he couldn't. I cracked a joke then by saying, "I think my dad did it." It came to me what's a good word in English to describe *turn and close*.

> My dad [**turns and closes**] jars and taps really hard. You can't get them open easy.

Is there a word to describe this? If not, what's a natural and fluent way to say this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's one word for it, but either [twist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twist) ("to cause to move with a turning motion") or [tighten](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tighten) ("to make tighter") carries some of the meaning.

If I had to say it, I think I would say something like, "He **closes them really tightly**."

Answer (score 1):

How about seal ("fasten or close securely")?

I would say, "He seals them firmly."

Comment: Including a link to dictionary for why this works would be an improvement to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

My dad **really tightens** things like jar lids and garden faucets. It's hard to get them to budge afterwards.